# How could spectators watch the Tri-Wizard events?

Tags: harry-potter, triwizard-tournament

If you're a contestant, away you go and do your things - good luck. But what could the students of Hogwarts watch? The first task seems ace - dragons and brooms, but task two happens under a lake, and task three is in a maze.

I wonder if somehow the students could see the action on a screen (a magic screen) but then the chapter after the lake we hear that everyone's hassling Harry and trying to find out what went on, because for them it was just an hour of lake.

What do you think? Do they do something in the films to imply what the audience gets to see?

Answer (score 15):

There is no clear information in the books (or accio quote) on what people could see as far as the lake task (people clearly saw the Dragon one).

However, we know from GoF's description of Quidditch World Cup that magical world has special binoculars that show things which in our world Google dubbed Augmented Reality and Google TV - they can freeze/slow the action down, they can overlay maneuver and player details on the image etc...

Comment: Why the down vote? He says what's in/not in the books then has his best guess. I for one can imagine underwater binoculars in the HP world.

Comment: The term "augmented reality" was certainly not dubbed by Google…

Answer (score 10):

The book doesn't explicitly state whether or not the spectators could see anything, but it heavily implies the second and third tasks cannot be seen.

After the second task, Dumbledore gets a report from a merperson on what happened during the task, which implies he himself didn't know. (emphasis is mine).

> Dumbledore was crouching at the water’s edge, deep in conversation
>   with what seemed to be the chief merperson, a particularly
>   wild and ferocious-looking female. He was making the same sort of
>   screechy noises that the merpeople made when they were above water;
>   clearly, Dumbledore could speak Mermish. Finally he straightened
>   up, turned to his fellow judges, and said, “A conference before
>   we give the marks, I think.” . . . “Ladies and gentlemen, we have reached our decision. **Merchieftainess Murcus has told us exactly what happened at the bottom of
>   the lake**...

During the third task, a lot of terrible things happen in the maze, including an unforgivable curse and the disappearance of two students. If the tasks were visible, why didn't Dumbledore do anything when Krum was using the cruciatus curse on Cedric? Had Harry not stepped in, Krum would have killed Cedric while under the imperious curse.

Again, it is never stated in the book whether or not the tasks were visible, but the evidence leans towards *no* for the second and third task.